# First time using security in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security

I have to do a homework where i have to implement user registration and login in ASP.NET.**(Form-Based)**

I am reading my book and it says that the first thing I should do is use `aspnet_regsql.exe` to configure, but when I went to pick the the database I get this error:
[image]

I keep trying to fix this problem, but I dont know how.
At this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) I found a note that says:

> The database elements that are
>   installed in the feature database will
>   always be owned by the SQL Server
>   database owner account (dbo). In order
>   to install the feature database, a SQL
>   Server login must be permitted to the
>   db_ddladmin and dd_securityadmin roles
>   for the SQL Server database. However,
>   you do not need to be a system
>   administrator for the SQL Server in
>   order to install the feature database.

I don't understand what I am missing.

-What should I do?

-Where can I find `db_ddladmin` and `dd_securityadmin`?

**UPDATE**

As the above step looks like is not able to find the database, i thought i better create it manually. so this is what i do
Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Why is this happening?

I just need to prepare my work enviroment to use form-based authentification. I cannot do my homework if i cant configure my working enviroment first. Can someone give me a hand to fix this? Does it have to do something with permisions or other?

Comment: First of all make sure that sql server is installed, and it has been started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you're trying to connect to a server that doesn't exist.  If you are using sql server express, your server name would be `creator-PC/SQLEXPRESS`.

I believe I remember having to do this too.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277.  Follow the instructions under "Enable remote connections for SQL Server 2005 Express or SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition"

Comment: @sfrj - See my update.  I think I remember having to allow remote connections in my sql express.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is try to browse to the database itself.  I use the sql server management studio to do this.  If you are able to connect, then you will need to edit the user permissions, otherwise you probably have an issue with the sql server setup.

Comment: Do you know where can i find some step by step tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry but i am confused. I did not create any data base at all. The text on my question is the first step i did. How can i create a db? I thought that it would be created automatically.

Answer (score 1):

if you tried connecting using management studio to your DB server and if you are able to connect but you are not able to connect through asp.net application then there is a probability that the database does not have any permission for `aspnet` user so first create a new user in `sql server` for `aspnet` user and try again to connect using the wizard.

Generally the error comes when you not have your server started or installed on machine. Also Make sure the server instance is running and you place the right name of the server instance. if your `sql server` is configured to use `sql server` authentication then provide proper parameters i hope this all will help and get you out of it

Comment: Wait a second. Should i use VS2005 to create a database first? i thought that wizard would create it for me.

Comment: do you know the name of your database server instance if you are using sql server express edition then it is by default machinename\SQLEXPRESS try this to put in the database server field

Comment: +1 to DevJosh for explaining my point much better.  You need SQL Server installed and working first, before VS will do anything.